# Spliting text into pandas dataframe : dealing with different dimension

Tags: python, string, dataframe, series

I am trying to split a `series` into pandas columns but i am dealing with the following issue :

```
df.head()

                 Opportunity Name     Amount Currency   Amount
       XXXX - XX - 2019 - 01 - 20                 ARS      300 
      YYY - YY - Y -2019 - 01 -21                 CHL      350
       ZZZZ - ZZ - 2019 - 03 - 25                 ARS      500
TT - TT - T - TT - 2019 - 04 - 26                 ARS     1000
```

Whenever i try to obtain a new dataframe where i can have the dates in a separate columns.
I used `str.split()` function with `expands=True` with split separator `-`

```
df['Opportunity Name'].str.split('-' , expand=True)
```

But my results are messy and difficult to pick those columns with the date beacuse it is split this way:

```
          0      1     2     3     4     5     6      
       XXXX     XX  2019    01    20  None  None
        YYY     YY     Y  2019    01    21  None
       ZZZZ     ZZ  2019    03    25  None  None
         TT     TT     T    TT  2019    04    26
```

Which makes difficult to slice over that dataframe, I just want to grab the date from that string datafrane column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Providing the real data is consistent with the sample data shown, in that the date characters are always at the end.
- Use the built-in function `isnumeric` and a list-comprehension to get the numbers in a list
- `''.join([...][-8:])` to combine only the last 8 characters
- `.to_datetime` to convert to a datatime format

```py
df['Date'] = df['Opportunity Name'].apply(lambda x: ''.join([y for y in x if y.isnumeric()][-8:]))
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

print(df)

                    Opportunity Name Amount Currency  Amount       Date
0        XXXX - XX - 32019 - 01 - 20             ARS     300 2019-01-20
1        YYY - YY - Y -2019 - 01 -21             CHL     350 2019-01-21
2         ZZZZ - ZZ - 2019 - 03 - 25             ARS     500 2019-03-25
3  TT - TT - T - TT - 2019 - 04 - 26             ARS    1000 2019-04-26
```

### Get the first value

```py
df['first_value'] = df['Opportunity Name'].apply(lambda x: x.split('-')[0].strip())
print(df)

                    Opportunity Name Amount Currency  Amount       Date first_value
0        XXXX - XX - 32019 - 01 - 20             ARS     300 2019-01-20        XXXX
1        YYY - YY - Y -2019 - 01 -21             CHL     350 2019-01-21         YYY
2         ZZZZ - ZZ - 2019 - 03 - 25             ARS     500 2019-03-25        ZZZZ
3  TT - TT - T - TT - 2019 - 04 - 26             ARS    1000 2019-04-26          TT
```

Comment: `df['Opportunity Name'].str.split('-' , expand=True)[0]` this should work

Comment: That won't get rid of the whitespace at the end, `'XXXX '`